# Program hangs at FD_SET macro in Linux Userspace

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am facing a problem with `FD_SET`. I am accessing CAN in Linux using socket CAN approach and using `recvfrom`. Since it is a blocking call, I want to use `select` system call. My program hangs @ `FD_SET` macro. It works fine with `FD_CLR` macro.

code :

```
FD_ZERO(&readfd);
printf("\n 1.1");
FD_CLR(s, &readfd);
printf("\n 1.2");
FD_SET(sockaddr,&readfd); //hangs here
printf("\n 1.3");
```

Output:

> 1.1
>    1.2

Not getting anything after that...

Even the `sockaddr` value is 3 (less than `FD_SETSIZE` = 1024);
I can apply `FD_SET` to socket can approach sockets??
What can be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that it's hanging at the `FD_SET()`. What's more likely is that `stdout` is a terminal, in which case your C library does line buffering so that each line is sent to the terminal only after the terminating newline is seen.

Try doing e.g. `printf("1.3\n")` instead (or just `puts("1.3")`, which is the same thing and simpler). You could also use a debugger.

(If `stdout` is a regular file, do an `fflush(stdout)` on it after printing "1.3" like
5gon12eder suggested in the comments. The `fflush()` will work regardless of whether `stdout` is a terminal or a regular file (which will use block buffering), so it's a nicer solution in that way. Another alternative is to use `stderr`, which is unbuffered by default.)

`FD_CLR(s, &readfd)` after `FD_ZERO(&readfd)` is redundant by the way. `FD_ZERO()` already clears the `fd_set` `readfd`.

*As for the real problem (the hang):*

That you're doing `FD_CLR(s, &readfd)` after `FD_ZERO(&readfd)` might indicate that you're misunderstanding something about how `select(2)` works. If you follow those lines with a `select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL)`, then the result will be that you're *only* ever waiting for the `sockaddr` file descriptor to become readable (to not block when read).

Also make sure that `readfd` is an `fd_set` and that `s` and `sockaddr` are descriptors (as returned by e.g. `socket(2)` and `open(2)`). Otherwise, things don't make sense.

Comment: I think that is not a problem with printf(), i have tried without printf() earlier and it hanged for debugging i have added printf() to the code..

Comment: @ganeshtenka: What happens if you do `printf("1.3\n");` instead? (The `\n` at the end is important, so that you get a full line, which is then sent to the terminal.)

Comment: Or use `fflush(stdout)`.  It always works without re-structuring your output logic and makes no assumptions what buffering strategy is used for `stdout`.

Comment: Just for completeness, a single `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` at the start of the program will disable buffering on `stdout` so that characters are sent immediately to the terminal. That's usually a bad idea though, especially if `stdout` might go to a file. `stderr` is unbuffered by default (probably specifically to preserve output in case of errors), so that's another alternative when doing quick-and-dirty `printf()`-based debugging.

Comment: @Ulfaizer I have tried with printf("1.3\n"); also it still hangs there..if(select(0 + 1, &readfd, NULL, NULL,NULL) == -1)
{
 perror("select");
}

Comment: @Ulfaizer I have tried with printf("1.3\n"); also it still hangs there..FD_ZERO(&readfd);
printf("1.1\n");
FD_CLR(s, &readfd);
printf("1.2\n");
FD_SET(s,&readfd); //hangs here
printf("1.3\n");     if(select(0 + 1, &readfd, NULL, NULL,NULL) == -1)
{
 perror("select");
}...Even readfd is an fd_set and that s is descriptor..

Comment: @ganeshtenka: Are you sure it's not crashing rather than hanging? What value do you get if you do `printf("%d\n", sockaddr)`?

Comment: Also, calling `select()` with 0+1 as the first argument won't work (though it's a different problem). 0 is not your highest-numbered file descriptor. Remember that descriptors are just `int`s.

Comment: I am sure it hangs only..sockaddr value is 3

Comment: @ganeshtenka: How are you compiling your program? Try adding `-E` (only run preprocessor) to the compilation command so you can see how the `FD_SET()` macro is expanded. (You can pipe to `less(1)` and search for some surrounding code with `/` to find where the expanded `FD_SET()` is.)

Comment: If you mean that you're sure that it's hanging on the `FD_SET()` itself, and not after.